# How to use row and column index in matrix value calculation in R without looping?

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

How can produce a matrix where the entries are, say, the product of the index of the row and column. For example:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    3    6    9
```

NB: this is not specific to multiplication. I actually need it to raise each entry to a power (row index - column index), and was looking to not have to induce loops (as I suspect there is a more R-friendly way).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the products:

```
 M <- matrix(NA, 3,3)
 Mrcprod <- row(M)*col(M)
```

R matrices are actually vectors with a dimension attribute. They behave with "vectorized" functions and operators in column major order.

```
> Mrcprod      # elementwise multiplication; NOT matrix multiplication
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    3    6    9
> c(Mrcprod)   # removes dimension attribute
[1] 1 2 3 2 4 6 3 6 9
```

To get the differences, just use a different operator:

```
M <- matrix(NA, 3,3)
M[] <- row(M)-col(M)
M
#------------
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0   -1   -2
[2,]    1    0   -1
[3,]    2    1    0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the outer product of `1:3` and `1:3`

```
outer(1:3,1:3)
# or
1:3 %o% 1:3
```

If you need the different of the row indices and column indices, use `outer` again

```
outer(1:3,1:3,"-")
```